# How to save a parsed Gherkin into a Feature File (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, cucumber, gherkin

I need to programatically modify feature files of cucumber.
I have parsed a feature file using gherkin's gem 'gherkin/parser'.

The problem I find is that after parsing, I end up with a hash with the following data as example:

```
{:type=>:GherkinDocument, :feature=>{:type=>:Feature, :tags=>[], :location=>{:line=>1, :column=>1}, :language=>"en", :keyword=>"Feature", :name=>"MyFeature", :description=>"  As an user\n  I want to test a feature", :children=>[{:type=>:Scenario, :tags=>[{:type=>:Tag, :location=>{:line=>5, :column=>3}, :name=>"@MyTag"}], :location=>{:line=>6, :column=>3}, :keyword=>"Scenario", :name=>"My scenario", :steps=>[{:type=>:Step, :location=>{:line=>7, :column=>5}, :keyword=>"Given ", :text=>"I start the app"}, {:type=>:Step, :location=>{:line=>8, :column=>5}, :keyword=>"And ", :text=>"I generate a test user"}, {:type=>:Step, :location=>{:line=>9, :column=>5}, :keyword=>"And ", :text=>"I finish the flow"}]}]}, :comments=>[]}
```

is it possible to convert this GherkinDocument generated by the parser to a plain text feature file to save it? What method or gem should I use to get

Comment: Is there a steps key in the has you get back?

Comment: @SanderSaelmans yes, I have edited to show the full hash that the parser returns now.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific about what you're trying to do? Could you perhaps "programatically modify" them with a simple regex instead of this?

Comment: What I'm doing is parse a feature file and modify the attribute name of all the scenarios that are included on the feature. Just need to save again as a feature file instead of the hash that the parser returns. I could do it with regex, but i think it would be a cleaner solution to do it with the tools that gherkin libs provide (if there is a possible solution)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/tree/master/gherkin), you would use the Ruby `Gherkin::Pickles::Compiler`:

```
require 'gherkin/parser'
require 'gherkin/pickles/compiler'
parser = Gherkin::Parser.new
gherkin_document = parser.parse("Feature: ...")
# Make changes to gherkin_document
pickles = Gherkin::Pickles::Compiler.new.compile(gherkin_document)
```

Comment: The output of the pickles are not a string nor a file ...